# Moving iron rod through solenoid

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetic-induction

[image: question]

What effect(s) does a moving iron rod have on a solenoid? Which of the graphs is correct?

Comment: Nothing would happen to iron bar since enf induced in rod is bvl b and v are either parallel or antiparallel ,so emf induced will be zero

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this page in the site help](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more on what topics you can ask about here.